# JSF - ignore case in URLs (OCPSoft)

Tags: jsf, prettyfaces, ocpsoft-rewrite

Is there a way to define rewrite rules in OCPSoft rewrite independent of case instead of defining multiple rules, since any character could be lower or upper case?

```
cb.addRule(Join.path('/Test').to("/test.xhtml"));
cb.addRule(Join.path('/test').to("/test.xhtml"));
```

Something like:

```
boolean ignoreCase = true;
cb.addRule(Join.path('/Test', ignoreCase).to("/test.xhtml"));
```

Background:

Logging our 404 errors i encounter a lot of requests just with lower case URLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! Absolutely.

The simplest way to do this is probably use a parameter with a regex `.matches()` constraint:

```
cb.addRule(
  Join.path('/{path}').to("/test.xhtml"))
      .where("path")
      .matches("(?i)test"); // <-- your path regex pattern goes here
```

You could also use the `Resource` or `Filesystem` condition with a custom transform to make this a more global rule:

```
public class Lowercase implements Transposition<String>
{
   @Override
   public String transpose(Rewrite event, EvaluationContext context, String value)
   {
      return value.toLowerCase();
   }
}
```

Then...

```
.addRule(Join.path("/{path}").to("/{path}.xhtml"))
.when(Resource.exists("{path}.xhtml"))
.where("path")
.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")
.transposedBy(new Lowercase())
```

This of course assumes that your xhtml files all use a lowercase naming scheme.

You could create your own custom `.when()` conditions to locate the most likely matches, then substitute the 'found / correct' value of `{path}` in the transposition, if you wanted to go even farther.

Comment: The regex solution looks good. Thank you and i will try this out.